# API Responding with 500 errors after significant load

Tags: box-api

I work at a cload integrations provider that uses Box's API to move data in and out of Box accounts for our clients.  We will easily hit the API tens or hundreds of thousands of times in a day.  Yesterday night I noticed a significant number of our API calls started receiving 500 errors with no json error body in the response.

Please let me know what the path is to try and resolve this problem as it is causing significant impact to our customers.

Answer (score 0):

[Per the documentation](http://developers.box.com/docs/#rate-limiting):

> In certain cases, Box needs to enforce rate-limiting in order to
>   prevent abuse by third-party services and/or users. In the event that
>   your service or a user of your service reaches an excessive level of
>   usage, a standard 503 error will be returned, with an indication of
>   when to retry the request. In the event that you receive back-to-back
>   503s, an exponential backoff algorithm is recommended.

Comment: If you read my post you will note that I am receiving 500's, not 503'.

Comment: Hm, that is indeed unexpected. Can you send a note to API[at]boxDOTcom including details about your API key and the requests your making?

Comment: In offline discussion we were not able to find the root cause, but discovered that this issue no longer appeared to be occurring.